# Grub error 452 out of range pointer

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub

When rebooted OS linux mint writes Grub Rescue. I fixed it by writing these commands

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub       
set root=(hd0,gpt3) 
insmod normal 
normal
```

Then when I entered the OS he wrote: **452 out of range pointer: 0x9cffe020 Backtrace (.text 0xa055 .data 0x15d6c): Aborted. Press any key to exit**

Help me please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is now not reproducible (the OS was reinstalled according to the user and it's therefore virtually impossible for them to apply any solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled Linux Mint to Fedora.

Comment: This was your approach, but in no way it is an acceptable solution to your described problem.

Comment: What is the acceptable answer then?

Comment: Any real solution to the original problem, it does not have to be your own answer, let others think on it. Cheers